# In which scenarios Node.js is useful

Tags: node.js

I have been reading about **Node.js**. But I don't understand why is it claimed to be powerful. In which scenarios does **Node.js** shine? and can it be used in general purpose web applications?

Comment: This question is not on-topic for Stackoverflow. Here, we expect questions that can have one *definitive* answer, that is not vague, and should be complete. This question does not fulfill those requirements, and as such it *may* be better on [programmers.SE].

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is event based in comparison to most other systems, used to build web applications. This lead to it being very controversial (some are very fond of it, others hate it…).
Aside of that controversy it can very well be used to build all kinds of web applications, and even big companies have done that so far (LinkedIn IIRC).

Felix, (former) node.js core contributor, wrote this [guide](http://nodeguide.com/convincing_the_boss.html), which shows quite well what node can/should (not) be used for.

Comment: I found good info in the guide you posted. Thanks :)